# My content pane show only white even if it has components on it

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I'm doing this as a challenge for myself. My problem is that when I click on the button, the content pane appears plain even if the `JPanel` has components in it.

I've tried adding the components on the frame but I get an error: >Cannot read field "parent" because "comp" is null.

I've tried other layout on `JFrame` and `JPanel` and still it didn't show.

Here's the full code:

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class test implements ActionListener{

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        new test();
    }
    static JPanel mainPanel, cubePanel;
    static JFrame frame;
    static Container container = new Container();
    static JLabel calculatorFor;
    static JButton sphereButton, rightCylinderButton, rightConeButton, rectangularPrismButton, triangularPrismButton,
            cubeButton, squarePyramidButton, rectangularPyramidButton, ellipsoidButton, tetrahedronButton ,backToPreviousFrameButton;
    static Font font = new Font(null, Font.PLAIN, 30);
    static JLabel enterValueForEdge;
    static JTextField edgeTextField;
    static JTextArea surfaceAreaTextArea, surfaceAreaFormulaTextArea, surfaceAreaSolutionTextArea;
    static JButton calculateButton;
    static double edge;
    static DecimalFormat surfaceAreaDecimal;
    public test(){
        frame = new JFrame("Calculating for Surface Area");

        calculatorFor = new JLabel("Calculator for the Surface Area of:");
        calculatorFor.setSize(600, 40);
        calculatorFor.setLocation(100, 50);
        calculatorFor.setFont(font);
        calculatorFor.setFocusable(false);

        sphereButton = new JButton("Sphere ");
        sphereButton.setSize(400, 40);
        sphereButton.setLocation(100, 100);
        sphereButton.setFont(font);
        sphereButton.addActionListener(this);
        sphereButton.setFocusable(false);

        rightCylinderButton = new JButton("Right Cylinder");
        rightCylinderButton.setSize(400, 40);
        rightCylinderButton.setLocation(100, 150);
        rightCylinderButton.setFont(font);
        rightCylinderButton.addActionListener(this);
        rightCylinderButton.setFocusable(false);

        rightConeButton = new JButton("Right Cone");
        rightConeButton.setSize(400, 40);
        rightConeButton.setLocation(100, 200);
        rightConeButton.setFont(font);
        rightConeButton.addActionListener(this);
        rightConeButton.setFocusable(false);

        rectangularPrismButton = new JButton("Rectangular Prism");
        rectangularPrismButton.setSize(400, 40);
        rectangularPrismButton.setLocation(100, 250);
        rectangularPrismButton.setFont(font);
        rectangularPrismButton.addActionListener(this);
        rectangularPrismButton.setFocusable(false);

        triangularPrismButton = new JButton("Triangular Prism");
        triangularPrismButton.setSize(400, 40);
        triangularPrismButton.setLocation(100, 300);
        triangularPrismButton.setFont(font);
        triangularPrismButton.addActionListener(this);
        triangularPrismButton.setFocusable(false);

        cubeButton = new JButton("Cube");
        cubeButton.setSize(400, 40);
        cubeButton.setLocation(100, 350);
        cubeButton.setFont(font);
        cubeButton.addActionListener(this);
        cubeButton.setFocusable(false);

        squarePyramidButton = new JButton("Square Pyramid");
        squarePyramidButton.setSize(400, 40);
        squarePyramidButton.setLocation(100, 400);
        squarePyramidButton.setFont(font);
        squarePyramidButton.addActionListener(this);
        squarePyramidButton.setFocusable(false);

        rectangularPyramidButton = new JButton("Rectangular Pyramid");
        rectangularPyramidButton.setSize(400, 40);
        rectangularPyramidButton.setLocation(100, 450);
        rectangularPyramidButton.setFont(font);
        rectangularPyramidButton.addActionListener(this);
        rectangularPyramidButton.setFocusable(false);

        ellipsoidButton = new JButton("Ellipsoid");
        ellipsoidButton.setSize(400, 40);
        ellipsoidButton.setLocation(100, 500);
        ellipsoidButton.setFont(font);
        ellipsoidButton.addActionListener(this);
        ellipsoidButton.setFocusable(false);

        tetrahedronButton = new JButton("Tetrahedron");
        tetrahedronButton.setSize(400, 40);
        tetrahedronButton.setLocation(100, 550);
        tetrahedronButton.setFont(font);
        tetrahedronButton.addActionListener(this);
        tetrahedronButton.setFocusable(false);

        backToPreviousFrameButton = new JButton("Back");
        backToPreviousFrameButton.setSize(100, 40);
        backToPreviousFrameButton.setLocation(900, 600);
        backToPreviousFrameButton.setFont(font);
        backToPreviousFrameButton.addActionListener(this);
        backToPreviousFrameButton.setFocusable(false);

        mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setBounds(0, 0, 1080, 720);
        mainPanel.setLayout(null);
        mainPanel.setBackground(Color.decode("#FAF7FC"));

        mainPanel.add(calculatorFor);
        mainPanel.add(sphereButton);
        mainPanel.add(rightCylinderButton);
        mainPanel.add(rightConeButton);
        mainPanel.add(rectangularPrismButton);
        mainPanel.add(triangularPrismButton);
        mainPanel.add(cubeButton);
        mainPanel.add(squarePyramidButton);
        mainPanel.add(rectangularPyramidButton);
        mainPanel.add(ellipsoidButton);
        mainPanel.add(tetrahedronButton);
        mainPanel.add(backToPreviousFrameButton);

        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.decode("#FAF7FC"));
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.setSize(1080,720);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public void cubePanel(){

        enterValueForEdge = new JLabel("Enter Edge:");
        enterValueForEdge.setSize(200, 40);
        enterValueForEdge.setLocation(100, 50);
        enterValueForEdge.setFont(font);
        enterValueForEdge.setFocusable(false);

        edgeTextField = new JTextField();
        edgeTextField.setSize(400, 40);
        edgeTextField.setLocation(300, 50);
        edgeTextField.setFont(font);

        calculateButton = new JButton("Calculate");
        calculateButton.setSize(200, 40);
        calculateButton.setLocation(100, 100);
        calculateButton.setFont(font);
        calculateButton.addActionListener(this);
        calculateButton.setFocusable(false);

        surfaceAreaFormulaTextArea = new JTextArea("SA = 6a²");
        surfaceAreaFormulaTextArea.setSize(400, 40);
        surfaceAreaFormulaTextArea.setLocation(100, 150);
        surfaceAreaFormulaTextArea.setFont(font);
        surfaceAreaFormulaTextArea.setEditable(false);

        surfaceAreaTextArea = new JTextArea("SA: ");
        surfaceAreaTextArea.setSize(500, 40);
        surfaceAreaTextArea.setLocation(100, 200);
        surfaceAreaTextArea.setFont(font);
        surfaceAreaTextArea.setEditable(false);

        surfaceAreaSolutionTextArea = new JTextArea();
        surfaceAreaSolutionTextArea.setSize(900, 80);
        surfaceAreaSolutionTextArea.setLocation(100, 250);
        surfaceAreaSolutionTextArea.setFont(font);
        surfaceAreaSolutionTextArea.setEditable(false);
        surfaceAreaSolutionTextArea.setLineWrap(true);

        backToPreviousFrameButton = new JButton("Back");
        backToPreviousFrameButton.setSize(100, 40);
        backToPreviousFrameButton.setLocation(900, 600);
        backToPreviousFrameButton.setFont(font);
        backToPreviousFrameButton.addActionListener(this);
        backToPreviousFrameButton.setFocusable(false);

        cubePanel = new JPanel();
        cubePanel.setBounds(0, 0, 1080, 720);
        cubePanel.setLayout(null);
        cubePanel.setBackground(Color.decode("#FAF7FC"));

        container = new Container();

        cubePanel.add(enterValueForEdge);
        cubePanel.add(edgeTextField);
        cubePanel.add(calculateButton);
        cubePanel.add(surfaceAreaFormulaTextArea);
        cubePanel.add(surfaceAreaTextArea);
        cubePanel.add(surfaceAreaSolutionTextArea);
        cubePanel.add(backToPreviousFrameButton);

        container.add(cubePanel);
        container.setLayout(null);
        container.setBackground(Color.decode("#FAF7FH"));
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if(e.getSource() == sphereButton){
            new sphereFrame();
            frame.dispose();
        }

        if(e.getSource() == rightCylinderButton){
            new rightCylinderFrame();
            frame.dispose();
        }

        if(e.getSource() == rightConeButton){
            new rightConeFrame();
            frame.dispose();
        }

        if(e.getSource() == rectangularPrismButton){
            new rectangularPrismFrame();
            frame.dispose();
        }

        if(e.getSource() == triangularPrismButton){
            new triangularPrismFrame();
            frame.dispose();
        }

       if(e.getSource() == cubeButton){
            frame.getContentPane().removeAll();
            frame.add(cubePanel);
            frame.repaint();
            frame.revalidate();
            System.out.println("Remove");
            frame.getContentPane().add(container);
       }
}
```

Comment: null layout is __wrong__, always! study https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/

Comment: 1) Class names should start with an uppercase character. Learn and follow Java naming conventions. 2) The usage of static variables is wrong. I suggest you read the [Swing tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html). You will find plenty of working example to help you better structure your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay particular attention to the [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) section.

Here's the GUI I created.

[image: Start]

Press the "Cube" button to bring up the page for the cube calculation.

[image: Cube calculation]

All Swing applications must start with a call to the `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater` method.  This method ensures that the Swing components are created and executed on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

The `JFrame` has a default `BorderLayout` and holds the main `JPanel`.  The main `JPanel` uses a [CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) to display the various calculation `JPanels`.  Using a `CardLayout` is much easier than managing multiple `JFrames` and provides a nicer user experience.

I used Swing layout managers to position the Swing components on the various `JPanels`.

The start `JPanel` consists of two subordinate `JPanels`.  The title `JPanel` uses a `FlowLayout` to display the title.  The button `JPanel` uses a `GridLayout` to display the various calculation `JButtons`.  You can create complex `JPanels` by nesting multiple simple `JPanels`.

The cube calculation `JPanel` was the only one you had in your code, so it was the only one I created.  I made it a method, but you can create a separate class for each of the calculations.  The cube calculation `JPanel` uses a `GridBagLayout` to create a form-like `JPanel`.  I used lambda expressions to create the `ActionListener` for each of the `JButtons`, since they were so simple.

I made the start `JPanel` button `ActionListener` a separate class just to get the code away from the `for` loop that creates the `JButtons`.

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class CardLayoutGUI implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new CardLayoutGUI());
    }

    private CardLayout cardLayout;

    private JTextField edgeTextField, surfaceAreaSolutionTextField;

    private JPanel mainPanel;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Calculating for Surface Area");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        this.mainPanel = createMainPanel();
        frame.add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        cardLayout = new CardLayout();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(cardLayout);
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 5, 5, 5));

        panel.add(createStartPanel(), "Start");
        panel.add(createCubeCalculationPanel(), "Cube");

        return panel;
    }

    private JPanel createStartPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 5, 5, 5));

        panel.add(createTitlePanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panel.add(createButtonPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        return panel;
    }

    private JPanel createTitlePanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 5, 5, 5));
        Font font = new Font(Font.DIALOG, Font.PLAIN, 36);

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Calculator for the Surface Area of:");
        label.setFont(font);
        panel.add(label);

        return panel;
    }

    private JPanel createButtonPanel() {
        String[] text = { "Sphere", "Right Cylinder", "Right Cone",
                "Rectangular Prism", "Triangular Prism", "Cube",
                "Square Pyramid", "Rectangular Pyramid", "Ellipsoid",
                "Tetrahedron" };
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 3, 5, 5));
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 5, 5, 5));
        Font font = new Font(null, Font.PLAIN, 24);
        ButtonListener listener = new ButtonListener();

        for (String s : text) {
            JButton button = new JButton(s);
            button.addActionListener(listener);
            button.setFont(font);
            panel.add(button);
        }

        return panel;
    }

    private JPanel createCubeCalculationPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 5, 5, 5));
        Font titleFont = new Font(null, Font.PLAIN, 32);
        Font font = new Font(null, Font.PLAIN, 16);

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 5, 5, 5);
        gbc.weighty = 1.0;

        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        JLabel label = new JLabel("SA = 6a²");
        label.setFont(titleFont);
        panel.add(label, gbc);

        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.gridy++;
        label = new JLabel("Edge:");
        label.setFont(font);
        panel.add(label, gbc);

        gbc.gridx++;
        edgeTextField = new JTextField(10);
        edgeTextField.setFont(font);
        panel.add(edgeTextField, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        label = new JLabel("SA:");
        label.setFont(font);
        panel.add(label, gbc);

        gbc.gridx++;
        surfaceAreaSolutionTextField = new JTextField(10);
        surfaceAreaSolutionTextField.setFont(font);
        surfaceAreaSolutionTextField.setEditable(false);
        panel.add(surfaceAreaSolutionTextField, gbc);

        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        JButton calculateButton = new JButton("Calculate");
        calculateButton.addActionListener(event -> {
            double edge = Double.valueOf(edgeTextField.getText());
            double sa = 6.0 * edge * edge;
            surfaceAreaSolutionTextField.setText(Double.toString(sa));
        });
        calculateButton.setFont(font);
        panel.add(calculateButton, gbc);

        gbc.gridy++;
        JButton backButton = new JButton("Back");
        backButton.addActionListener(event -> {
            cardLayout.show(mainPanel, "Start");
        });
        backButton.setFont(font);
        panel.add(backButton, gbc);

        return panel;
    }

    public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            JButton button = (JButton) event.getSource();
            String text = button.getText();
            cardLayout.show(mainPanel, text);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this :

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Test2 implements ActionListener {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test2();
    }

    static JPanel mainPanel, cubePanel;
    static JFrame frame;
    static Container container = new Container();
    static JLabel calculatorFor;
    static JButton sphereButton, rightCylinderButton, rightConeButton, rectangularPrismButton, triangularPrismButton,
            cubeButton, squarePyramidButton, rectangularPyramidButton, ellipsoidButton, tetrahedronButton, backToPreviousFrameButton;
    static Font font = new Font(null, Font.PLAIN, 30);
    static JLabel enterValueForEdge;
    static JTextField edgeTextField;
    static JTextArea surfaceAreaTextArea, surfaceAreaFormulaTextArea, surfaceAreaSolutionTextArea;
    static JButton calculateButton;
    static double edge;
    static DecimalFormat surfaceAreaDecimal;

    public Test2() {
        frame = new JFrame("Calculating for Surface Area");

        calculatorFor = new JLabel("Calculator for the Surface Area of:");
        calculatorFor.setSize(600, 40);
        calculatorFor.setLocation(100, 50);
        calculatorFor.setFont(font);
        calculatorFor.setFocusable(false);

        sphereButton = new JButton("Sphere ");
        sphereButton.setSize(400, 40);
        sphereButton.setLocation(100, 100);
        sphereButton.setFont(font);
        sphereButton.addActionListener(this);
        sphereButton.setFocusable(false);

        rightCylinderButton = new JButton("Right Cylinder");
        rightCylinderButton.setSize(400, 40);
        rightCylinderButton.setLocation(100, 150);
        rightCylinderButton.setFont(font);
        rightCylinderButton.addActionListener(this);
        rightCylinderButton.setFocusable(false);

        rightConeButton = new JButton("Right Cone");
        rightConeButton.setSize(400, 40);
        rightConeButton.setLocation(100, 200);
        rightConeButton.setFont(font);
        rightConeButton.addActionListener(this);
        rightConeButton.setFocusable(false);

        rectangularPrismButton = new JButton("Rectangular Prism");
        rectangularPrismButton.setSize(400, 40);
        rectangularPrismButton.setLocation(100, 250);
        rectangularPrismButton.setFont(font);
        rectangularPrismButton.addActionListener(this);
        rectangularPrismButton.setFocusable(false);

        triangularPrismButton = new JButton("Triangular Prism");
        triangularPrismButton.setSize(400, 40);
        triangularPrismButton.setLocation(100, 300);
        triangularPrismButton.setFont(font);
        triangularPrismButton.addActionListener(this);
        triangularPrismButton.setFocusable(false);

        cubeButton = new JButton("Cube");
        cubeButton.setSize(400, 40);
        cubeButton.setLocation(100, 350);
        cubeButton.setFont(font);
        cubeButton.addActionListener(this);
        cubeButton.setFocusable(false);

        squarePyramidButton = new JButton("Square Pyramid");
        squarePyramidButton.setSize(400, 40);
        squarePyramidButton.setLocation(100, 400);
        squarePyramidButton.setFont(font);
        squarePyramidButton.addActionListener(this);
        squarePyramidButton.setFocusable(false);

        rectangularPyramidButton = new JButton("Rectangular Pyramid");
        rectangularPyramidButton.setSize(400, 40);
        rectangularPyramidButton.setLocation(100, 450);
        rectangularPyramidButton.setFont(font);
        rectangularPyramidButton.addActionListener(this);
        rectangularPyramidButton.setFocusable(false);

        ellipsoidButton = new JButton("Ellipsoid");
        ellipsoidButton.setSize(400, 40);
        ellipsoidButton.setLocation(100, 500);
        ellipsoidButton.setFont(font);
        ellipsoidButton.addActionListener(this);
        ellipsoidButton.setFocusable(false);

        tetrahedronButton = new JButton("Tetrahedron");
        tetrahedronButton.setSize(400, 40);
        tetrahedronButton.setLocation(100, 550);
        tetrahedronButton.setFont(font);
        tetrahedronButton.addActionListener(this);
        tetrahedronButton.setFocusable(false);

        backToPreviousFrameButton = new JButton("Back");
        backToPreviousFrameButton.setSize(100, 40);
        backToPreviousFrameButton.setLocation(900, 600);
        backToPreviousFrameButton.setFont(font);
        backToPreviousFrameButton.addActionListener(this);
        backToPreviousFrameButton.setFocusable(false);

        mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setBounds(0, 0, 1080, 720);
        mainPanel.setLayout(null);
        mainPanel.setBackground(Color.decode("#FAF7FC"));

        mainPanel.add(calculatorFor);
        mainPanel.add(sphereButton);
        mainPanel.add(rightCylinderButton);
        mainPanel.add(rightConeButton);
        mainPanel.add(rectangularPrismButton);
        mainPanel.add(triangularPrismButton);
        mainPanel.add(cubeButton);
        mainPanel.add(squarePyramidButton);
        mainPanel.add(rectangularPyramidButton);
        mainPanel.add(ellipsoidButton);
        mainPanel.add(tetrahedronButton);
        mainPanel.add(backToPreviousFrameButton);

        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.decode("#FAF7FC"));
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.setSize(1080, 720);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public Container cubePanel() {

        enterValueForEdge = new JLabel("Enter Edge:");
        enterValueForEdge.setSize(200, 40);
        enterValueForEdge.setLocation(100, 50);
        enterValueForEdge.setFont(font);
        enterValueForEdge.setFocusable(false);

        edgeTextField = new JTextField();
        edgeTextField.setSize(400, 40);
        edgeTextField.setLocation(300, 50);
        edgeTextField.setFont(font);

        calculateButton = new JButton("Calculate");
        calculateButton.setSize(200, 40);
        calculateButton.setLocation(100, 100);
        calculateButton.setFont(font);
        calculateButton.addActionListener(this);
        calculateButton.setFocusable(false);

        surfaceAreaFormulaTextArea = new JTextArea("SA = 6a²");
        surfaceAreaFormulaTextArea.setSize(400, 40);
        surfaceAreaFormulaTextArea.setLocation(100, 150);
        surfaceAreaFormulaTextArea.setFont(font);
        surfaceAreaFormulaTextArea.setEditable(false);

        surfaceAreaTextArea = new JTextArea("SA: ");
        surfaceAreaTextArea.setSize(500, 40);
        surfaceAreaTextArea.setLocation(100, 200);
        surfaceAreaTextArea.setFont(font);
        surfaceAreaTextArea.setEditable(false);

        surfaceAreaSolutionTextArea = new JTextArea();
        surfaceAreaSolutionTextArea.setSize(900, 80);
        surfaceAreaSolutionTextArea.setLocation(100, 250);
        surfaceAreaSolutionTextArea.setFont(font);
        surfaceAreaSolutionTextArea.setEditable(false);
        surfaceAreaSolutionTextArea.setLineWrap(true);

        backToPreviousFrameButton = new JButton("Back");
        backToPreviousFrameButton.setSize(100, 40);
        backToPreviousFrameButton.setLocation(900, 600);
        backToPreviousFrameButton.setFont(font);
        backToPreviousFrameButton.addActionListener(this);
        backToPreviousFrameButton.setFocusable(false);

        cubePanel = new JPanel();
        cubePanel.setBounds(0, 0, 1080, 720);
        cubePanel.setLayout(null);
        cubePanel.setBackground(Color.decode("#FAF7FC"));

        container = new Container();

        cubePanel.add(enterValueForEdge);
        cubePanel.add(edgeTextField);
        cubePanel.add(calculateButton);
        cubePanel.add(surfaceAreaFormulaTextArea);
        cubePanel.add(surfaceAreaTextArea);
        cubePanel.add(surfaceAreaSolutionTextArea);
        cubePanel.add(backToPreviousFrameButton);

        container.add(cubePanel);
        container.setLayout(null);
        container.setBackground(Color.getColor("#FAF7FH"));
        return container;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (e.getSource() == sphereButton) {
            new sphereFrame();
            frame.dispose();
        }

        if (e.getSource() == rightCylinderButton) {
            new rightCylinderFrame();
            frame.dispose();
        }

        if (e.getSource() == rightConeButton) {
            new rightConeFrame();
            frame.dispose();
        }

        if (e.getSource() == rectangularPrismButton) {
            new rectangularPrismFrame();
            frame.dispose();
        }

        if (e.getSource() == triangularPrismButton) {
            //new triangularPrismFrame();
            frame.dispose();
        }

        if (e.getSource() == cubeButton) {
            frame.getContentPane().removeAll();
            frame.add(cubePanel());
            frame.repaint();
            frame.revalidate();
            System.out.println("Remove");
            frame.getContentPane().add(container);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: (1-) This answer doesn't explain what the problem is or what you did to fix the problem.

Comment: Downvoted, need explanation.

Comment: it works, but how does it work?